# Attempted import error: 'useThemeVariants' is not exported from '@material-ui/styles'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does anybody know why am I getting this error and how should I fix it?

I have tried nuking the node modules and re-installing, also tried with former versions. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when you update MaterialUI to version `5.0.0-alpha.5`. Updating your package to the next version (`5.0.0-alpha.6`) will fix it.

Related [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21982).

[image: Edit dazzling-monad-06735]